# I cannot remove decimals C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, decimal

Im making a car game using Unity3D & C# and I want to show the speed, but I cannot remove decimals. Help please.

I have searched for over an hour now, but nothing solves my problem.

```
var speed = Convert.ToString(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6); 
speed = String.Format("{0:C0}", speed);
Camera.FindObjectOfType<TextMesh>().text = speed;
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PabPe.jpg)

Comment: Cast the speed variable to an int

Comment: @Nick I cannot, I get the following errors when I do: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string, Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string', Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int''. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @derHugo Same result. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a `string` to

```
String.Format("{0:C0}", speed);
```

the formatter only works on numeric values (`int`, `float`, `double`, ...) **not** on a `string`.

See also more information about [custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) and [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) since [`"C0"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier) is for `Currency` and probably not what you are looking for. You might rater want to use either [`"N0"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier) for `Numeric` or simply use a custom string as below.

You didn't really specify what exactly your output should look like and if you want to cutoff all decimals or only up to a specific precision.

---

Rather directly pass it in like

```
                                      // Also note the f here for a float multiplication!
                                      //                       |
                                      //                       v
var speed = (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f).ToString("0.00");
```

or

```
var speed = (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f).ToString("0");
```

---

Alternatively you can as mentioned in comments also use [`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html) in order to round to an int value first

```
var speed = Mathf.RoundToInt(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f).ToString();
```

---

Sidenote:

A final sidenote on efficiency:

It seems like you want to be using this in e.g. `Update` repeatedly ... don't!

Rather use `Find` and `GetCompnent` only once at gamestart and re-use the references later:

```
// if possible even reference this in the Inspector right 
// away than you don't need the Awake method at all
[SerializeField] private RigidBody rigidBody;
[SerializeField] private TextMesh textMesh;

privtae void Awake()
{
    if(!rigidBody) rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if(!textMesh) textMesh = Camera.FindObjectOfType<TextMesh>();
}

privtae void Update()
{
    var speed = Convert.ToString(rigidBody.velocity.magnitude * 3.6); 
    speed = String.Format("{0:C0}", speed);
    textMesh.text = speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `C` format stands for 'currency'. The following code using the `N` modifier, as 'number':

```
decimal speed;
speed = 2.4m;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0}", speed));
speed = 2.5m;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0}", speed));
speed = 2.6m;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0}", speed));
```

produces results like this:

```
2
3
3
```

It works the same for `float` and `double` types.

Note that in you code `speed` is a string, which, obviously, won't work with a number format.